# How to make closable tabs with Meteor? My solution, your feedback

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, spacebars

Note: as I wrote this question, I solved it. Since I think it would be  useful for both others and me to have feedback on my approach, I finished explaining the different steps. Feel free to comment/answer.

Hello,

I want to dynamically load/unload tabs using a dropdown for loading and a close button for unloading. I use bootstrap.

See my answer for the approach.

Comment: Billbobbonnet, please separate your answer from your question.  Post the question part as a question, and add your answer part as an answer.  Stack Exchange isn't your blog.

Comment: agreed, this could have been a good answer but instead it is a bad question.

Comment: Done. I only wanted to be helpful instead of just keeping it to myself. If it stays downvoted, I'll just delete the question.

Comment: Don't delete it, that hurts you more than the downvotes.  Instead, edit it to match what SO considers to be a good question ([ask]). It'll get upvotes and the downvotes may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what seems to me the best way to achieve that:

1. In my template.created function, I create a local collection as follows

   ```
   tabs = new Meteor.Collection(null);
   ```
2. I create an array to hold my collection data

   ```
   var myArray = [
   {
           "name": "List",
           "template": "This is the list view",
           "loaded": true,
           "active": true,
           "diplayed": true,
           "icon": "fa fa-bars"
       },
       {
           "name": "Gallery",
           "template": "This is the gallery view",
           "loaded": false,
           "active": false,
           "diplayed": false,
           "icon": "fa fa-bars"
       }
   ];
   ```
3. I iterate on my array to load every item in my local collection

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
       tabs.insert(myArray[i]);
   }
   ```
4. I load my collection elements using `{{#each loadedTabs}}` for the nav-tab and `{{#each nonLoadedTab}}` for the dropdown. Here are what the helpers look like:

   ```
   nonLoadedTabs: function(){
       return tabs.find({"loaded":false})
   },
   ```
5. I add an event attached to the close button and another to the dropdown select

   ```
   'click .closeTab' : function(){
       tabs.update (this._id, {$set: {loaded:false}});
   },
   'click .tab_load_button' : function(){
       tabs.update (this._id, {$set: {loaded:true}});
   }
   ```
6. Now I must add with the "active" class to the right tab in order to let bootstrap deal with the tab content display. To do this, I add a few lines to my click events.

   The load event unset the "active" tab item and add it to the current one:

   ```
   'click .tab_load_button' : function(){
       //remove the "active" in other tabs
       $(".nav-tabs").each(function() {
           if($(this).find("li.active")) {
               $(this).find("li.active").removeClass("active");
           }       });
       //update the newly loaded/active tab
       tabs.update (this._id, {$set: {loaded:true, active:true}});
   }
   ```

   or alternatively using my "active" field in both operations:

   ```
   'click .tab_load_button' : function(){
        //remove the "active" in other tabs
        tabs.update ( {active:true}, {$set: {active:false}});
        //update the newly loaded/active tab
        tabs.update (this._id, {$set: {loaded:true, active:true}});
   }
   ```

The close button set the "active" class to the first loaded tab found (couldn't find how to get the last):

```
    'click .closeTab' : function(){
    tabs.update (this._id, {$set: {loaded:false}});
    //if we closed an active tab...
    if (this.active){
        //set the first loaded tab as active
        tabs.update ( {loaded:true}, {$set: {active:true}},{multi:false});
    }
},
```